# Descriptions for KML Paths on Google Earth for iOS

Tags: kml, google-earth, mobile, ios

I am displaying hurricane paths on Google Earth where if you click on a path it shows a description in a window containing info such as wind speeds, category, location, etc. This works perfectly fine on the desktop version of GE.

My problem comes on the mobile side. Google Earth only displays the path and when I click on a path there is no description. I know this is a long shot since GE hasn't updated their iOS app in ages, but does anyone know a workaround for this or any suggested alternative apps that can resolve this?